# Mouse Out of Element and Mouse Into Another Element Does Not Reset State

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-darwin-w0i5pk?file=/src/App.js

**Description:**
This is just 4 gray squares that each get their own shade of gray. I want to change the background color of each square when the user hovers over each, but I want the hover color to be +10 in RGB of what it was originally.

**Issue:**
When I mouse/hover out of one of the gray squares and mouse/hover into another gray square, the first square does not switch back to its initial color state.

**Help:**
Can someone explain why it is doing this and how to fix it because I have no idea?

**Note:**
I am trying not to use CSS for the hover because I am specifying the backgroundColor with JS.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const tabs = [
  { name: "1", img: [] },
  { name: "2", img: [] },
  { name: "3", img: [] },
  { name: "4", img: [] }
];

const initialState = {};

tabs.forEach((t, i) => {
  initialState[i] = false;
});

export default function App() {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(initialState);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {tabs.map((t, i) => {
        const v = 50 - (i + 1) * 10;
        const val = hover[i] ? v + 10 : v;

        return (
          <div
            key={t.name}
            className="tab"
            onMouseOver={() => {
              setHover({
                ...hover,
                [i]: true
              });
            }}
            onMouseLeave={() => {
              setHover({
                ...hover,
                [i]: false
              });
            }}
            onMouseOut={() => {
              setHover({
                ...hover,
                [i]: false
              });
            }}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: `rgb(${val}, ${val}, ${val})`,
              height: "100px",
              width: "100px"
            }}
          >
            <p>{t.name}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**This picture only shows the initial state:**

[image: not changing back to initial state]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` calls are not what a human would consider "immediate". Instead, the calls to the state setter as queued inside React internal mechanisms. Consider this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0)

// somewhere

setState(state + 1)
setState(state + 1)
```

In this case, you do not end up with `2` but `1`, because while you call `setState` twice to increment by one, you really are calling it as:

```
setState(1)
setState(1)
```

This is the exact issue in your code with the callbacks, you have

```
// enter
setState({ ...state, [i]: true })
// leave
setState({ ...state, [i]: false })
```

so when both get called, you apply the "leave" with the wrong previous state.

This is why `setState` has another pattern, `setState(prevState => nextState)`

```
setState(prevState => prevState + 1)
setState(prevState => prevState + 1)
```

Like this, you do end up with the value `2` because the second call is then using the "correct" previous state.

In your case, you need:

```
// enter
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [i]: true }))
// leave
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [i]: false }))
```

Comment: I'm getting my brain wrapped around how react state doesn't work immediately because after playing around with it, what you said about it makes sense. Thanks for that explanation.

Comment: If you want to get more to the bottom of that, loop up "stale closures in JS", the concept/issue is not React exclusive, it's just everywhere in React functional components ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you also keep the previous values in your state. You should update in this way

```
onMouseOver={() => {
              setHover({
                [i]: true
              });
            }}
            onMouseLeave={() => {
              setHover({
                [i]: false
              });
            }}
            onMouseOut={() => {
              setHover({
                [i]: false
              });
            }}
```